# how to solve this specific Oracle query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following tables :

COUNTRIES :

[image]

LOCATIONS :

[image]

What I'm trying to do is to select `COUNTRY_ID` and `COUNTRY_NAME` from COUNTRIES only if `STATE_PROVINCE` in the table `LOCATIONS` is equals to `null` .

what I've done so far :

```
select country_id, country_name
from countries
union 
select country_id
from locations
where state_province = null;
```

but this is doesn't seem to work !

EDIT : I forget to specify that I've to write this query without using `JOIN`

Comment: and what if there was an state_province which is not null, for the country which has state_province=null ?

Comment: I want to select only countries that don't have a state province ! so they're state province needs to be = null ..

Comment: @downvoter please care on leaving a comment !! what's wrong with this question so I learn from my mistakes !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to select only countries that don't have a state province ! so
> they're state province needs to be = null
>
> I've to write this query without using
> JOIN

```
select ctr.country_id, ctr.country_name
from countries ctr
where not exists (select l.country_id
                  from locations l
                  where l.state_province is not null and l.country_id=ctr.country_id)
```

Comment: thx for your answer but the problem is I'm not allowed to use JOIN :/

Comment: @ZeRubeus so answer edited, can you please check it?

Comment: "L"."COUNTRY_ID": invalid identifier :/

Comment: you are welcome bro, happy to see the issue got fixed.

Answer (score 1):

How about you use a join rather than a union?

```
select distinct countries.country_id, countries.country_name
from countries
left join locations
on countries.country_id = locations.country_id
where locations.state_province is null;
```

Comment: Might want to use a left join, just in case a country has no locations.

Comment: Yep, I was just thinking about that.